# Kubernetes pods serving un-equal amount of traffic

Tags: kubernetes, devops

I have a situation in which an application has total kubernetes 6 pods in production environment and upon checking the logs 1 pod is serving 30  percent of the entire traffic and rest of the 5 pods are serving 70 percent traffic in total.

How can we make sure all the 6 pods serves equal amount of traffic because I am suspecting the pod alone which is serving almost 30 percent traffic may gets exited which is not desirable as per the production environment.

Is there any core service of kubernetes which is not functioning well which is why the traffic distribution is non-uniform?

Question: How can we make sure that all the pods should serve equal amount of traffic??

Comment: did you enabled `externalTrafficPolicy: Local` in your service ?

Comment: I am using a loadbalancer. This attribute is not there.

Comment: does kubelete executes that attribute by default even if it not set?

Comment: no, It does not set default attr `externalTrafficPolicy: Local`.

Comment: It is very hard to advise anything thru internet based on what you mentioned. Providing some more context like config files, place where you running your workloads, os & versioning would be definitely beneficial.